# enter (sub) selection not firing

Tags: d3.js

Given the following doc,

running example here: https://blockbuilder.org/max-l/497143f7e012e488d413c43d098db462

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 960).attr("height", 500)

svg.append("text")
    .text("update").attr("y", 100).attr("font-size", 36)              
    .on("click", () => {            
        data[0].counter += 1
        update()
    })                          

const data = [{id: 123, counter:0}]
```

The following enter selection never fires,
If I changed the select for the one commented
i.e.:  d3.selectAll("text.counter")
then the enter and update selection fire appropriately,
but the problem is that the insertion is in the doc,
not as a child of the svg element

```
const update = () => {

  const counter = 
     d3.select("svg").selectAll("text.counter")
     //d3.selectAll("text.counter")
        .data(data, c=>c.id)

  counter
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("class","counter")
    .merge(counter) 
    .text(c => c.counter)
}

update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the text some location

```
  counter
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("class","counter")
    .attr("y", 50)
    .merge(counter)
    .text(c => c.counter);
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it, the text was being added, it was just not visible, so the enter selection *was* firing after all...